# MIPS Pipeline stages for Load Immediate

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, immediate-operand

I understand there are 5 standard stages for an instruction in MIPS. for the following pseudo instruction

```
li $t1, 0      # pseudo-instruction for addi $t1, $zero, 0
```

Can anyone please confirm if this uses all 5 stages? I think underlying this is an `addi` but I don't really understand if it needs to use the MEM stage?

My thinking is that the immediate value is stored in the instruction, not in memory, so wouldn't the WB stage do the register load?

Comment: What does it mean to you to "use" a pipeline stage?

Comment: A pseudoinstruction does not use any pipeline stages, because it is not an instruction that the processor pipeline can execute. Your question is meaningless.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't very clear - I meant all instructions are composed of a number of "stages" in the datapath pipeline (IF, ID, EX, MEM, WB) - I was asking if the 'addi' used the MEM stage. Appears not.

Comment: EOF - I put the underlying instruction there (addi) - please read more carefully, it might make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This instruction will translate into an `addi $t1, $0, 0` or some other such.

All stages do useful work to execute even such simple computational instructions — *except the MEM stage*.

Only load and store instructions require the data memory pipeline stage (MEM).  If it wasn't for them, we wouldn't have a MEM stage.  (Of course, we would also have a processor that can't do much, either.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming.